# Map data structure terminology

Tags: data-structures, terminology

I'm looking for the correct terminology in regard to map (dictionary) data structure.

When I'm talking about the semantics of the values stored in map in the direction from keys to values, I'd say, for example

> messages keys are mapped to message strings

When I'm using the opposite direction - describing the values first, I'd need to say something like

> message strings are ??? by message keys ("being mapped by" just doesn't feel right here)

Comment: Are the images of. PS What has your research on this shown?

Comment: @philipxy it has shown that this opposite direction of talking about the values and keys in map is seldom used, I couldn't find a single example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about "message strings are associated with keys"?